# Merge multidimensional array using Underscorejs

Tags: underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

```
[{"ic_value1":"PTP-1","in_id":"80"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-2","in_id":"81"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-3A","in_id":"82"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-3B","in_id":"83"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-4","in_id":"84"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-5A","in_id":"85"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-5B","in_id":"86"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-6","in_id":"87"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-7","in_id":"88"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-8","in_id":"89"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-9A","in_id":"90"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-9B","in_id":"91"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-10","in_id":"92"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-11","in_id":"93"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-12A","in_id":"94"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-13","in_id":"95"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-13","in_id":"96"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-14","in_id":"97"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-15","in_id":"98"},{"ic_value1":"PTP-16","in_id":"99"},{"ic_value1":"DH-129","in_id":"100"},{"ic_value1":"DH-130","in_id":"101"}]

[{"ic_value1":"09+75","in_id":"80"},{"ic_value1":"09+75","in_id":"81"},{"ic_value1":"09+09","in_id":"82"},{"ic_value1":"09+09","in_id":"83"},{"ic_value1":"09+06","in_id":"84"},{"ic_value1":"08+08","in_id":"85"},{"ic_value1":"08+08","in_id":"86"},{"ic_value1":"08+08","in_id":"87"},{"ic_value1":"08+00","in_id":"88"},{"ic_value1":"07+10","in_id":"89"},{"ic_value1":"06+00","in_id":"90"},{"ic_value1":"06+00","in_id":"91"},{"ic_value1":"04+43","in_id":"92"},{"ic_value1":"10+99","in_id":"93"},{"ic_value1":"10+83","in_id":"94"},{"ic_value1":"03+84","in_id":"95"},{"ic_value1":"03+84","in_id":"96"},{"ic_value1":"04+52","in_id":"97"},{"ic_value1":"03+94","in_id":"98"},{"ic_value1":"04+54","in_id":"99"},{"ic_value1":"07+82","in_id":"100"},{"ic_value1":"07+42","in_id":"101"}] 

[{"ic_value1":"112D","in_id":"80"},{"ic_value1":"190D","in_id":"81"},{"ic_value1":"096D","in_id":"82"},{"ic_value1":"096D","in_id":"83"},{"ic_value1":"184D","in_id":"84"},{"ic_value1":"092D","in_id":"85"},{"ic_value1":"092D","in_id":"86"},{"ic_value1":"190D","in_id":"87"},{"ic_value1":"040D","in_id":"88"},{"ic_value1":"040D","in_id":"89"},{"ic_value1":"010D","in_id":"90"},{"ic_value1":"010D","in_id":"91"},{"ic_value1":"017D","in_id":"92"},{"ic_value1":"060D","in_id":"93"},{"ic_value1":"020D","in_id":"94"},{"ic_value1":"007D","in_id":"95"},{"ic_value1":"007D","in_id":"96"},{"ic_value1":"024D","in_id":"97"},{"ic_value1":"048D","in_id":"98"},{"ic_value1":"050D","in_id":"99"},{"ic_value1":"095D","in_id":"100"},{"ic_value1":"080D","in_id":"101"}]
```

How do i align this three array into row and column. Every first item containing same `in_id` and I want to put it a row and column

Expected output:

```
[{80: ["PTP-1","09+75","112D"]]
```

something similar like this

How to achieve it using underscorejs

Comment: Could you please include the expected output?

Comment: What about 81, 82 and 83?

Comment: should be appended. If length of first array is not the same as the second, null value should be applied

Comment: Please include that also in the question. Till the question is clear, most people will not be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the ids seem to appear in every of the three arrays in the same order, it's as simple as

```
_.map(_.zip(array1, array2, array3), function(row) {
    var o = {};
    o[row[0].in_id] = _.pluck(row, "ic_value1");
    return o;
});
```